# Converting std::vector<cv::Point2f> into an image

Tags: opencv

I have a vector of 2 dimensional floating points in OpenCV's data structure cv::Point2f. I also have rgb values for each point in another structure. I want to create a CV32FC3 cv::Mat by combining the first two data structure. If the points were integer, that is cv::Point2i, I could have inserted the color value in x, y index given by the cv::Point2i, but as they are cv::Point2f, how would I convert them to image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert each point to cv:Point2i, i don't think there is other way. Sooner or later you will have to convert coordinates of points from floats to integers, because dimensions (and somehow coordinates) in cv::Mat are always integers - you can't set color of pixel P(3.5, 3.14) - coordinates will be always converted to integers.